# Android Studio: showing variable usages instead of declarations on ctrl+click

Tags: android-studio

In the following Kotlin code

```
private lateinit var userListenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        userListenerRegistration =
                FirestoreUtil.addUsersListener(this.activity!!, this::updateRecyclerView)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false)
    }
```

why does  <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on `userListenerRegistration` produce it's usages? I have verified in in `settings->keymaps` that <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> corresponds to showing declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing on something pretty easy here. If I am correct, you are referring to the first line of your code. The variable `userListenerRegistration` is being declared in this line. So, <kbd>ctrl+click</kbd> should have redirected to this line itself. However, AS instead shows you its usages, which is more sensible, IMO.

Try clicking on other variables, say, `LisetenerRegistration` and you should be directed to it's declaration.

PS: In other code editors like VSCode, you will not see this behaviour.